# upload froala images on s3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, froala

I am using **react-froala-wysiwyg** editor in my application. but i am having trouble uploading images on s3 bucket. when i am trying to upload images on the s3; s3 returns error forbidden: 403.

Can anyone share the configuration for uploading image on the s3 for reactjs.

**Following is my configuration.**

```js
var config = {

  imageUploadToS3: {
    bucket: 'testing-s3upload',
    // Your bucket region.
    region: 'us-east-1',
    keyStart: 'froalaUploads/',
    params: {
      acl: 'public-read',
      AWSAccessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
      AWSSecretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      policy: '', // i have no policy applied on my bucket.
      signature: '',
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Asper the froala editor documentation:**

> In order to get the image uploaded to S3, it is necessary to compute a
>   signature using the `AWS access key ID` and `AWS secret access key`
>   and provide it together with the upload request. The rich text editor
>   Ruby SDK comes with methods to compute the S3 signature using the V4
>   signing algorithm that works with buckets created on any of the S3
>   regions.

They have also provided with a sample:

```
class UploadController < ActionController::Base

  ...

  def index
    # Configuration object.
    options = {
      # The name of your bucket.
      bucket: 'bucket-name',

      # S3 region. If you are using the default us-east-1, it this can be ignored.
      region: 'eu-west-1',

      # The folder where to upload the images.
      keyStart: 'uploads',

      # File access.
      acl: 'public-read',

      # AWS keys.
      accessKey: 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY',
      secretKey: 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY'
    }

    # Compute the signature.
    @aws_data = FroalaEditorSDK::S3.data_hash(options)
  end

  ...

end
```

*In your case you have not created a signature, that must be the error.*

**[Official Link](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/sdks/ruby/image-s3-upload)**